# Python / Google API client v3 / ensuring thread safety

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to 'implement' thread safety by generating a new `http` object per http request as introduced in this Google API python client [documentation page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/thread_safety.md#thread-safety).

For authentication, I am using a seervice account and 2 ways appear possible to generate this `http` object, and providing required credentials.
I tried these and got following errors:

1/

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery, http

# Get authorization
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/home/me/Documents/code/store3.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

def build_request(creds):
  new_http = creds.authorize(build_http())
  return http.HttpRequest(new_http)

drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=scoped_credentials, requestBuilder=build_request(scoped_credentials))
```

Error is then:
`AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'authorize'`

2/

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery, http

# Get authorization
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/home/me/Documents/code/store3.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

import google_auth_httplib2
def build_request(creds):
  return google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp(creds, http=http.build_http())

drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=scoped_credentials, requestBuilder=build_request(scoped_credentials))
results = drive.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```

Error is then:
`TypeError: 'AuthorizedHttp' object is not callable`

Hmmm, I am lost.
Please, do you know where the trouble may come from?
Thanks for your help.
Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from the [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/thread_safety.md#thread-safety) the parameter `requestBuilder` expects a function reference not an object (pay attention to the missing parentheses in `requestBuilder=build_request`. Make sure your function has a matching signature to the example.